# Flutter - VSCode isn't completing dart code, selecting widget by suggestion box auto-completes just name

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

As shown in the `gif` I am clicking `ENTER` which ideally should complete the whole definition & I would have to simply edit it, but here it just completes the name of the Widget (Not even brackets are closed)

It was working well before 2 days suddenly have stopped working, and am falling short of keywords to find exactly what could be the issues.

I have tried reinstalling VSCode but doesn't work & in Android Studio it works fine as required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make sure you downloaded the `Flutter` and `Dart` plugin from VS code.

Comment: Have both installed